# hibernate repeat query

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I have Web app(as ORM I use **Hibernate**) that populates data from **Oracle 11** DB.
For short period of time some Oracle packages becomes invalid and then becomes valid back (it's legacy data load and during this process user can use other UI).

When data load finishes and user perform any query to those packages I have an error:

> ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded ORA-04061:
>   existing state of package "sche.pck" has been invalidated ORA-04065:
>   not executed, altered or dropped package "sche.pck" ORA-06508: PL/SQL:
>   could not find program unit being called: "sche.pck"

If user press F5 (on error message screen) then the query executes successfully. If there any way to repeat user query when such errors happen?

Answer (score 3):

Yes - try/catch the exception, inspect the exception message, looking for `ORA-04068`, and if it is found, rerun the query.

Ideally, you should have a number of retries. Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    try {
          executeQuery();
          break; //if successful;
    } catch (..) {
        if (!ex.getMessage().contains("ORA-06508")){
             throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Looks a bit hacky, and I'd suggest to try to fix the original problem instead.

Update:

It seems you have to do that in many places, so the above will be tedious. If you really cannot fix the underlying oracle problem, you can try wrapping your DataSource, Connection and Statement objects into your own implementations that simply delegate to the underlying object, but in the case of `executeQuery()`, performs the retry.

Comment: The problem is.... I can't do it in the whole app! If I use interceptor, I don't have access to the real query, to repeat it. Not so easy, huh?

Comment: you should've shared these details earlier ;)